# A Familia(l)r Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

My family and I love to be united in four or five

My name can be hard to pronounce, and I won't apologize

My brother's always crying, really pulling on the heart

And not many people can tell us two apart

Upon hearing my name, others shudder

*I don't neck in the halls, unlike my brother* ***(THIS LINE SHOULD BE DISREGARDED,*** I've made a mistake. The riddle is still solvable.)

I've always read differently than the rest of my family

And here's a hint: I've not got an E.

**Who or what am I?**

Hint 1)

> When I'm with my family, we all work together.

Hint 2)

> One might say I'm more just than the rest of my species.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE!

Comment: I can't decipher all of the clues yet, but it sounds a bit like something from ROT13(Gur Crevbqvp Gnoyr bs Ryrzragf)

Comment: perhaps it's something to do with rot13(zhfvp abgrf be fpnyrf)??

Comment: Never mind, I broke the code. I'll add some hints!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a

> Cello

My family and I love to be united in four or five

> String quartet or quintet

My name can be hard to pronounce, and I won't apologize

> Italian ch

My brother's always crying, really pulling on the heart

> Violin or viola, having a mournful voice-like sound

And not many people can tell us two apart

> Would make more sense for a violin and viola, unless the brother is a double/upright bass

Upon hearing my name, others shudder
I don't neck in the halls, unlike my brother

> (Not sure about these)

I've always read differently than the rest of my family

> Not starting with viol-

And here's a hint: I've not got an E.

> No E string, unlike e.g. a guitar

Comment: +1 You've essentially got it, congratulations! See my answer for detailed solution.

Answer (score 3):

A guess with a couple clues unaccounted for... Are you the

> King of spades?

My family and I love to be united in four or five

> Either in four of a kind (KKKK) or in royal straights (10,J,Q,K,A)

My name can be hard to pronounce, and I won't apologize

> Unsure.

My brother's always crying, really pulling on the heart

> Meaning the King of hearts, who appears to be pulling a sword through his head

And not many people can tell us two apart

> All Kings are the same rank in most card games

Upon hearing my name, others shudder

> In Poker, a King beats anything but an Ace

I don't neck in the halls, unlike my brother

> Unsure

I've always read differently than the rest of my family

> The King of spades faces right, while all the others face left

And here's a hint: I've not got an E.

> In narrowing down the potential face cards 'King' has no E, but 'Queen' does

Title:

> Cards are very familiar, and the answer is part of the royal Family

Comment: But the "King of Spades", as you answered, does have an E

Comment: Actually, it does have an `E`: "king of spad**E**s"

Comment: Very creative! +1, but **this is not the correct answer**. Keep guessing!

Answer (score 0):

It's a partial answer still, but are you

> Aluminium?

My family and I love to be united in four or five

> Aluminium has 3 valence electrons, so it can form a bond with 4 atoms in it

My name can be hard to pronounce, and I won't apologize

> People pronounce Aluminum differently, it is a controversial word

My brother's always crying, really pulling on the heart

> Not sure, but I imagine that some neighboring element could hold the clue

And not many people can tell us two apart

> Unsure

Upon hearing my name, others shudder

> I am strictly against Aluminium. Whenever I see aluminium foil, I set it on fire

I don't neck in the halls, unlike my brother

> Dunno

I've always read differently than the rest of my family

> Aluminium is pronounced many odd ways.

And here's a hint: I've not got an E.

> Aluminium has no E

Comment: for "not many people can tell us apart", maybe r13(gva nf nyhzvahz sbvy va puvarfr vf 錫紙, naq 錫 va snpg vf gva, fb znlor gva jvyy qb?)

Comment: I do enjoy seeing such creative responses. However, **this is not the correct answer**. Keep guessing!

Answer (score 0):

### INTENDED SOLUTION (SELF-ANSWER)

> Tommy Jollyboat pretty much has it! The answer is: Viola

My family and I love to be united in four or five

> As TJ guessed, this refers to string quartets and string quintets.

My name can be hard to pronounce, and I won't apologize

> When people see the word viola, they often attempt to pronounce it similar to violin (it should rhyme with bee-oh-lah, not bye-oh-la)

My brother's always crying, really pulling on the heart

> TJ got this one too; violin is often stereotyped as "sad" and "mournful"

And not many people can tell us two apart

> Very few people can tell violas and violins apart, as TJ notes. Even I can't unless one is held next to the other!

Upon hearing my name, others shudder

> Viola is often mocked as sounding ugly and nasty compared to violin *(this is a major clue as to which string instrument it is)*

I don't neck in the halls, unlike my brother

> This refers to the chinrest on a violin, which can make it seem as though the violin is kissing the player's neck, and the "halls" are concert halls. I was under the mistaken impression that violas didn't use chinrests in the orchestra, **so this clue is pretty much invalid.**

I've always read differently than the rest of my family

> Violas, of course, read alto clef, unlike violins, cellos, and double basses *(this was the other big hint about which string instrument it was)*

And here's a hint: I've not got an E.

> No E-string on the viola.